# What does rebuilding content access permissions do?

Tags: users

Since installing the node access module I see the following message randomly.

> Content access permissions need to be rebuilt.

Will rebuilding them remove all the node access permissions already set? What does "rebuilding" do? Why do I get this message?

Answer (score 5):

There's a quote in the comments on [this post](http://drupal.org/node/957992) that puts it nicely:

> Drupal maintains a table of who can access what; this needs to be rebuilt when a new module affecting user access is enabled.

Think of it as a cache-clear for node access data, except that it's quite complicated so needs to be run as a batch job rather than all at once (e.g. on a cron run).

Since node access is a sensitive issue it's also not wise to rely on scheduled jobs to make the necessary changes, hence why this is all done in one go.

Comment: This is all correct as you seem to mean "batch job" informally, as synonym to "cron job" and "all in one go". In the code, there is something called "batch mode" for rebuilding permissions, and this is something else. It will distribute rebuilding over several batches, doing one per HTTP request to avoid timeouts. The permission rebuilding function can be run in this batch mode (usually done when run from a browser) and non-batch mode (usually done when run via cron).

Comment: Is it as harmless as clearing caches, or should I always do a backup beforehand? 'Cuz, let's be real. I don't do backups before clearing caches. :) Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I also was getting this error, after installing the **Book Access** module in Drupal 6.
It turns out I hadn't created any books yet, so that after I had clicked the check box to enable the new installed module, drupal was unable to find found any book permissions with which to initialise the new database table that **Book Access** uses.

I was able to get rid of the error by

1. disabling **Book Access**
2. creating a book page

   - no need for content, but do include at least a title
   - remember to select "new book" from the dropdown box in the "Book Outline" section of the "edit" tab
3. enabling **Book Access** again

Your situation may be similar.

Answer (score 0):

I've been frustrated at times trying to find how to run this process manually on D8 / D9 - top Google results are useless. So, if you know you have a content access issue (content that should be viewable is being restricted, for example), then navigate to:

`yoursite.com/admin/reports/status/rebuild`

The reason is that a problem with content access permissions is shown as an item on your status report, and the rebuild command comes from there. But you can navigate directly to the above URL at any time if you need to kick off a rebuild. (Don't do it casually as it's a tedious operation - only if you know you have content that is incorrectly being hidden, or not hidden, especially by a custom module or a wacky contrib module like `permissions_by_term`.)