# Resetting admin cache

Tags: caching, routes, users

I am having an issue with the cache on my site's admin section.  I recently created a module that includes some admin pages.  I made a mistake with hook_menu, setting the wrong permissions for the settings at admin/zipcodes.  I got an access denied error.  I subsequently fixed the error but still get access denied.  I've reset the site cache, but it appears that the admin section is still using some cache somewhere.  I've had a similar issues in the past and am wondering if there's a way to get Drupal to purge the cache in the admin section.

Below is the page definition I created in hook_menu that is giving me an access denied error. As far as I can see it's working fine, and I'm guessing in the morning it will work as well.  It's just a little frustrating to have to now wait several hours before I can continue.

```
$items['admin/zipcodes'] = array(
  'title' => 'Statistics',
  'description' => 'List statistcs.',
  'page callback' => 'zipcodes_stats_page',
  'access callback' => 'user access',
  'access arguments' => array('administer content'),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  'menu' => 'menu-administrative-menu',
  'file' => 'zipcodes.admin.inc',
);
```

Comment: Did you try to rebuild permissions? see this question for more info: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33436/what-does-rebuiling-content-acess-permissions-do

Comment: `'access callback' => 'user access'` is wrong, PHP function names can't have spaces in them